# Is it true? $\dim(U+W)=\dim(U\cap W)+1$ implies $U\subseteq W$

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis

I'm curious whether or not this statement is true.

If $U,W$ are finite-dimensional space satisfying $\dim(U+W)=\dim(U\cap W)+1,$ then $U\subseteq W.$

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: I think you mean $W$ not $V$. (And you can also have $W \subseteq U$, no ?)

Comment: Let $U$ be $\mathbb R^2$ and $W$ any $1$-dimensional subspace of $U$.

Comment: and of course you probably want to cosider only finite-dimensional sapces

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes its only finite-dimensional

Comment: @nicomezi Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose not. Then 
$$\dim(U+V)\geq \max(\dim(U),\dim(V))+1>\dim(U\cap V)+1$$
the first inequality follows from the fact that there is one vector in each of the two spaces which does not belong to the span of the other, so the dimension of the cumulative span becomes larger.

The second inequality is strict because of the same reason: the intersection must be of dimension strictly less than the maximal dimension of the two spaces.

---

EDIT: now that we know that either $U\subseteq V$ (or conversely), we note that
$$U+V=V\quad \text{and}\quad  U\cap V=U.$$
thus the equality becomes
$$\dim(V)=\dim(U)+1$$

Comment: This is interesting, thank you. What if we are going to proof directly, My question: how two spaces subset each other relates to their dimension?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? I can't understand what exactly you mean by "how two spaces subset each other relates to their dimension"

Comment: If we want to conclude, say $U\subset V,$ can we deduce such inclusion by the condition only from the dimension of U and of V?

Comment: I've completed my answer, see above